# google form script addon onEdit(e) not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a google script that I made from a google form. I typed in the following code and it all runs fine.

```
function onEdit(e){
  form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(form.getDestinationId())

  transferAnnouncments();
}
```

However, when I edit my form it does not run the code. I haven't published anything or added any other time-based triggers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*This doesn't run because Google Forms do not support `onEdit()` triggers.*

#### More Information:

As per the documentation on [Event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_forms_events), there are only two types of triggers for Google Forms: `onOpen()` and `Form submit` (the latter is only installable, whereas the former can be either a [simple](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) or [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) trigger.